(Number of) 2-sheeted coverings of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times S^1$
I recently came across a question, asking for the number of 2-sheeted covering maps of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times S^1$ (up to equivalence), and I really have no clue.
There are at least three for sure, but I am unsure if there are more and furthermore how to prove that properly.
As the fundamental group of the space is $(\mathbb{Z}\setminus 2\mathbb{Z})\times \mathbb{Z}$, it would be basically sufficient to find represents for each subgroup containing exactly the elements (for some fixed integer $k$), $(1,(2n+1)k)$ and $(0, 2nk)$ for all $n$, as the other subgroups are relatively easy to classify.
I think this can maybe be done with some quotient space of $S^2\times S^1$ or something and utilising the groups to build it somehow? But I am very clueless at this point.

$n$-fold coverings up to equivalence are in bijection with index $n$ subgroups of the fundamental group. One way to find all the index $n$ subgroups of an abelian group $G$ is to find all index $n$ subgroups of $G/nG$–make this statement precise, and then try finishing from here.
